# How to custom print on Xcelsius

Tags: xcelsius

Xcelsius comes with a print button, but what it does is to print a screenshot of the dashboard, what I need to do, is to do a custom print of a single table or chart, and not
the entire dashboard, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the print button included with the product is not very versatile. Outside of writing your own print component in flex here are some tricks you may want to consider...

Use dynamic visibility to put a background that obscures the rest of the dashboard prior to printing. ex: make a fake Print Preview button that sets everything up how you want it printed on the page then have the user click the real print button.

Use an external interface connection to isolate the Xcelsius chart into its own SWF container that is fed its data by the main application through a JS interface.

And if all else fails you could always perform a print screen capture and crop the picture to the desired view.